# Android: Change APN settings by code

Tags: android, settings, apn

As in my country (Belgium) a lot of operators settings are not included in default APN list, i would like to create an app that will fill all APN fields correctly with the user choice.

I just read all the doc and Google a lot of questions but no answer...

How should I do to create an APN profile?

Thank a lot for any clue.